# Docker - No module named 'celery_worker'

Tags: docker, celery

I am trying to build a `celery` container in docker, like so:

```
  celery:
    image: dev3_web
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./services/web:/usr/src/app
      - ./services/web/logs:/usr/src/app
    command: celery worker -A celery_worker.celery --loglevel=INFO -Q cache
    environment:
      - CELERY_BROKER=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis
    links:
      - redis:redis


  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.3-alpine
    restart: always
    expose:
      - '6379'
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'


  monitor:
    image: dev3_web
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    command:  flower -A celery_worker.celery --port=5555 --broker=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - web
      - redis
```

which runs from `docker-compose-dev.yml`.

but I'm getting the error:

```
celery_1   | Traceback (most recent call last):
celery_1   |   File "/usr/bin/celery", line 10, in <module>
celery_1   |     sys.exit(main())
celery_1   |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 16, in main
celery_1   |     _main()
celery_1   |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 322, in main
celery_1   |     cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
celery_1   |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 496, in execute_from_commandline
celery_1   |     super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
celery_1   |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 273, in execute_from_commandline
celery_1   |     argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
celery_1   |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 479, in setup_app_from_commandline
celery_1   |     self.app = self.find_app(app)
celery_1   |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 501, in find_app
celery_1   |     return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
celery_1   |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 359, in find_app
celery_1   |     sym = symbol_by_name(app, imp=imp)
celery_1   |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 504, in symbol_by_name
celery_1   |     return imports.symbol_by_name(name, imp=imp)
celery_1   |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/imports.py", line 56, in symbol_by_name
celery_1   |     module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
celery_1   |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/imports.py", line 104, in import_from_cwd
celery_1   |     return imp(module, package=package)
celery_1   |   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
celery_1   |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
celery_1   |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
celery_1   |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
celery_1   |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
celery_1   | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'celery_worker'
```

> Folder structure:

```
web/
   dockerfile
   celery_worker.py
   project/ 
          __init__.py
```

> **web/celery_worker.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from project import celery, create_app

app = create_app()
app.app_context().push()
```

> **web/project/__init__.py**

```
import os
# third party libs
from flask import Flask  
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from celery import Celery
from flask_debugtoolbar import DebugToolbarExtension
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_mail import Mail

# instantiate the db
db = SQLAlchemy()
# background processes instance
celery = Celery(__name__, broker='redis://redis:6379/0')
# extensions
toolbar = DebugToolbarExtension()
cors = CORS()
migrate = Migrate()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()  
mail = Mail()

def create_app(script_info=None):
    from .api import routes

    # instantiate the app
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # set config
    app_settings = os.getenv('APP_SETTINGS')
    app.config.from_object(app_settings)

    # set up extensions
    db.init_app(app)
    toolbar.init_app(app)
    cors.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)   
    # register blueprints
    routes.init_app(app)
    #models.init_app(app)
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    # shell context for flask cli
    @app.shell_context_processor
    def ctx():
        return {'app': app, 'db': db}

    return app
```

> In my **web/Dockerfile**  I have set working directory like so:

```
(...)

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

(...)
```

Fhis setting used to work with `flask`, prior to me using docker containers, running the following at root:

`celery worker -A celery_worker.celery --loglevel=INFO -Q cache`

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you setting your working dir as `/usr/src/app` in your Dockerfile?

Comment: yes. `Step 8/15 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
celery:
  image: dev3_web
  restart: always
  volumes:
    - ./services/web:/usr/src/app
    - ./services/web/logs:/usr/src/app   # <--- here is your problem
```

You are loading in the logs subdirectory over the app directory in the compose file. The last one listed wins, so you will only have an empty folder or some log files, with no code in the running container.

Comment: I thought that volumes were only local copies

Comment: Volumes are not local copies. These are _bind mounts_, which act as if a host path is a container path. The first bind mount is setting the container path `/usr/src/app` to work with the host path of `$(pwd)/services/web`. The second bind mount is overriding that to instead map the container path `/usr/src/app` to work with the host path of `$(pwd)/services/web/logs`, as if the first volume definition never existed at all. See https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ for a primer on the types of volumes and how they behave.